# Access JSON generated via Flixter API

Tags: javascript, json, rotten-tomatoes

I am trying to develop a web app to leverage flixster API (Rotten Tomatoes)
I a trying to access url at : `http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=w697y3tvc9n4arza5vcnx9zt&q=alien`

I  am pretty sure there is a way to include this cross domain JSON or shall i simply include url of the app just like any other src/css ?

```
function callflixapi() {
    var url ='http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?callback=jsonprequest&apikey=w697y3tvc9n4arza5vcnx9zt&q=alien';
}

function jsonprequest(response){
    console.log(response);
}
```

This is the code i use using jsonp. I call callflixapi on body load of document

Comment: Just a note:  You probably don't want to share your api key in this posting.  Others can use it and fill up your api request limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSONP support

http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/JSON

EDIT: JSONP explanation

http://json-p.org/

Comment: function callflixapi() {
    var url ='http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?callback=jsonprequest&apikey=w697y3tvc9n4arza5vcnx9zt&q=alien';
    }
    function jsonprequest(response){
    console.log(response);
    }

Comment: @user1290495,  You have posted the correct code. Does this mean it is working now?

Comment: i had to ,make some more changes.. but it was... thank you :)